# Ошибка при запуске проекта связанная с подключёнными библиотеками

Tags: java, android, библиотеки

Подключил две библиотеки:

commons-net-3.5.jar

commons-io-2.5.jar

При запуске проекта вылезает следующая **ошибка**:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE.txt
File1: C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\Sender0.4\app\libs\commons-io-2.5.jar
File2: C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\Sender0.4\app\libs\commons-net-3.5.jar
```

Немного погуглив нашёл решение, код, который нужно прописать в build.gradle(module:app):

```
packagingOptions { exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE' } { exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'}
```

но это не помогло, а даже усугубило ситуацию, вызвав ошибку при сборке проекта.

**Код build.gradle(module:app):**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.user.sender04"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile files('libs/commons-net-3.5.jar')
compile files('libs/commons-io-2.5.jar')
}
packagingOptions {
exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
}
```

так должно сработать

---

Вы вставили мой фрагмент не в тот раздел. Надо так:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.user.sender04"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile files('libs/commons-net-3.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-io-2.5.jar')
}
```

Comment: к сожалению это тоже не помогло, та же самая ошибка, ошибка при сборке проекта

Comment: @Engineman, 1. покажите ошибку, 2. покажите файл build.gradle

Comment: Error:(29, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'packagingOptions()'
Possible causes:The project 'Sender0.4' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Open Gradle wrapper fileThe build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin

- ошибка

Comment: файл build.gradle  добавил в описание

Comment: @Engineman, обновил ответ

Comment: да, заработало!спасибо за помощь, надеюсь, что данный вопрос ещё поможет кому-нибудь тк информации по данной ошибке очень мало и интернете